# Error in connecting to estimote beacon iOS

Tags: c#, ios, ibeacon, estimote

Every time  I try to connect with estimote beacons using the `ConnectToBeacon` method, I get this error:

> Beacon not in range, has outdated software or is Virtual beacon.

but the same beacon is having proximity 2 and rssi value as -72.

Below is a snapshot of the code I tried:

```
public class ConnectingToBeacon : ESTBeaconDelegate
{
    ESTBeacon samplebeacon;

    public ConnectingToBeacon(ESTBeacon beacon)
    {
        samplebeacon = beacon;
        samplebeacon.Delegate = this;
        samplebeacon.ConnectToBeacon();

    }

    public override void ConnectionDidFail (ESTBeacon beacon, NSError error)
    {
        Console.WriteLine ("Proximity " + beacon.Ibeacon.Proximity.ToString ());
    }

}
```

Am I missing something?

Answer (score 1):

Please try using the Estimote iOS app to update your beacon to the latest FW (2.1) over the air.

Cheers.

Answer (score 0):

Get the latest SDK from https://github.com/Estimote/iOS-SDK.
Try, connecting to beacons using Estimote App to make sure beacons are actually working or not.

If you are not able to find beacons using Estimote App as well then battery life of your beacons might be over.